# htaccess redirect 301 all users from old folder with dash to newfolder, same domain

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I want to move users who type or click on google results

```
http://example.com/name-lname/chicago
```

to

```
http://example.com/namelname/chicago
```

i tried

```
Redirect 301 ^name-lname namelname
```

but i got error 500
how can i fix it?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
RewriteRule ^name-lname$ /namelname? [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this rule as your very first rule in root .htaccess:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/name-lname(/.*)?$ /namelname$1
```

`RedirectMatch` provides regex capability against `Redirect` directive.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use RedirectMatch as Redirect does not support regex :

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/([^-]+)-([^/]+)/(.+)$ /$1$2/$3
```

Answer (score 0):

For this kind of simple redirects, you do not need regexes, so you do not need mod_rewrite or RedirectMatch, simple Redirect is enough :

```
Redirect 301 /name-lname /namelname
```

Query strings and additionnal path parts will be added to the target URL. From the [doc](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect):

> Then any request beginning with URL-path *(note: the /name-lname part)* will return a redirect
>   request to the client at the location of the target URL. Additional
>   path information beyond the matched URL-path will be appended to the
>   target URL.

But note that `http://example.com/name-lnamefile.html` will not be matched.